# What is the simplest way i can page a nested data repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with a two nested data repeaters, and I want to allow paging for the outer repeater.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="group">
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="question"><%#Eval("QText") %></div>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# setQID(Eval("QID"))%>' />

        <%--  THE INNER REPEATER--%>     
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2">
                 <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div class="answer">
                 </HeaderTemplate>
                 <ItemTemplate>

                        <%# (GetAnswer(Eval("AnsQID"))) != 1 ? (displayAnswer(Eval("AText"))) : ""%>

                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    </div>
                </FooterTemplate>

       </asp:Repeater>
       <%--  THE INNER REPEATER ENDS HERE--%>   

        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </div>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

I have googled for this, searched everywhere and found a lot of ways to approach this. I am using `LinqDatasources` and two repeaters. What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To page the outer repeater i have used the method outlined in [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx) in the past. I don't think it should make much difference to the outcome if your repeater is nested. Your inner repeater will count as one row.

Repeaters generally though don't have great support for paging. You could consider using [ListView](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125144848/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021308-1.aspx) (if using ASP.Net 3.5 or greater) or [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx) (ASP.Net 2.0 or greater)  which have more support for paging out of the box.

Comment: thanks, but i am using this because i want more control over the output. The PagedDatasource object seems a viable option, how do i get around doing that ?

Comment: @Shane Adrian Muaz - fair comment about control. I think the ListView though gives you as much as the repeater (not the GridView though). In answer to your question through - this link http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345 seems to be doing what you want. I'm not sure if you could integrate the LINQDatasource objects. I suspect that you will have to bind the LINQ query direct to the paged datasource. The nested repeater being bound on the ItemDataBound event. Does that help?

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz No probs. Vote me up if it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have used this control in my Project.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CollectionPager.aspx
optional
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/SQLPager_For_Everything.aspx

and **for Nested you have to use Databoud event and bound the child repeater.**